# Regex Help String Matching

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a long string in the format of:

```
WORD_1#WORD_3#WORD_5#CAT_DOG_FISH#WORD_2#WORD_3#CAT_DOG_FISH_2#WORD_7
```

I'm trying to dynamically match a string so I can return its position within the string.

I know the string will start with `CAT_DOG_` but the `FISH` is dynamic and could be anything. It's also important not to match on the `CAT_DOG_FISH_2(int)`

Basically, I need to get back a match on any word starting with `[CAT_DOG_]` but not ending in `[_(int)]`

I've tried a few different think and I don't seem to be getting anywhere, any help appreciated.

Once I have the regex to match, I'll be able to get the index of the match, then work out when the next `#`(delimiter) is , which will get me the start/end position of the word, I can then substring it out to return the full word.

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Add `regex` which you've tried

Comment: Try this [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/fV0jF5/2).  `(CAT_DOG_[^\d]*)#`

Comment: or this one
(CAT_DOG_[a-zA-Z]*)#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, since i know the int the string will end with I've settled on this:

```
 int i = 0;

        string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split('#');

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (word.StartsWith("CAT_DOG_") && (!word.EndsWith(i.ToString())) )
            {
                //process here
                MessageBox.Show("match is: " + word);
            }
        }
```

Thanks to Eser for pointing me towards String.Split()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
\bCAT_DOG_[a-zA-Z]+(?!_\d)\b
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CbCAT_DOG_%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B(%3F!_%5Cd)%5Cb&i=WORD_1%23WORD_3%23WORD_5%23CAT_DOG_FISH%23WORD_2%23WORD_3%23CAT_DOG_FISH_2%23WORD_7)

Or (if the `FISH` is really anything, but not `_` or `#`):

```
\bCAT_DOG_[^_#]+(?!_\d)\b
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CbCAT_DOG_%5B%5E_%23%5D%2B(%3F!_%5Cd)%5Cb&i=WORD_1%23WORD_3%23WORD_5%23CAT_DOG_FISH%23WORD_2%23WORD_3%23CAT_DOG_FISH_2%23WORD_7)

The word boundaries `\b` with the look-ahead `(?!_\d)` (meaning that there must be no `_` and a digit) help us return only the required strings. The `[^_#]` character class matches any character but a `_` or `#`.

You can get the indices using LINQ:

```
var s = "WORD_1#WORD_3#WORD_5#CAT_DOG_FISH#WORD_2#WORD_3#CAT_DOG_FISH_2#WORD_7";
var rx1 = new Regex(@"\bCAT_DOG_[^_#]+(?!_\d)\b");
var indices = rx1.Matches(s).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Index).ToList();
```

[image]

Values can be obtained like this:

```
var values = rx1.Matches(s).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

[image]

Or together:

```
var values = rx1.Matches(s).OfType<Match>().Select(p => new { p.Index, p.Value }).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: If there is any doubt, please let me know. BTW, you can also use `.OfType<Match>()` instead of `.Cast<Match>()`.

Comment: Also, check [`\bCAT_DOG_(?![^#]*_\d)[^#]*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbCAT_DOG_(%3f!%5b%5e%23%5d*_%5cd)%5b%5e%23%5d*&i=WORD_1%23WORD_3%23WORD_5%23CAT_DOG_FISH%23WORD_2%23WORD_3%23CAT_DOG_FISH_2%23WORD_7), maybe it will work better for you, since we do not know your input well.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I avoid Regex whenever possible as I find them hard to read and maintain unless you use them a lot, so here is a non-regex solution:

```
string words =  "WORD_1#WORD_3#WORD_5#CAT_DOG_FISH#WORD_2#WORD_3#CAT_DOG_FISH_2#WORD_7";
var result = words.Split('#')
    .Select((w,p) => new { WholeWord = w, SplitWord = w.Split('_'), Position = p, Dynamic = w.Split('_').Last() })  
    .FirstOrDefault(
        x => x.SplitWord.Length == 3 && 
        x.SplitWord[0] == "CAT" && 
        x.SplitWord[1] == "DOG");
```

That gives you the whole word, the dynamic part and the position. I does assume the dynamic part doesn't have underscores.